# What's the meaning of the phrase "take a swing out"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Just **take a swing out** to Rockaway after work

I saw this sentence in the movie *The Flamingo Kid*.
What's the meaning of the phrase "take a swing out" here?

Comment: I think *swing* here just means *a quick journey*. *Just take a quick journey out to Rockaway after work.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "swing by" or "swing past" is an idiom that means **to stop briefly at one location on the way to another**.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/swing-by-past-somewhere

It is implied the new location is somewhere between the start and end of the trip, so this extra stop would be convenient.

The joke is that [Rockaway, Queens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockaway_Beach,_Queens) is on a peninsula so it is not "on the way" to anywhere. It is probably the most remote and inconvenient location in New York City.